# How can I format `pre` so that it can behave like picture in text area?

Tags: html, css

To show code in my div area, I have used `<pre  class="prettyprint linenums:0" > code </pre>` statement. However, the code shown not like as I expected. I have expect it has its own block like picture and text continue like;

```
Sunday, ...
 ______
| code |  However, George should ...
|      |  ...
|______|  ...
At the same time, in the ....
```

However, I have got like;

```
Sunday, ...
 _________________________
| code                   |
|                        |
|________________________|
However, George should ...
...
...
At the same time, in the ....
```

How can I format `pre` so that it can behave like picture in text area?

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you want the `<pre>` element to behave like an inline element, not a block element. To change this, you need to set the `display` property of your `<pre>` to `inline`.

So, you can try:

```
<pre class="prettyprint linenums:0" style="display: inline;"> code </pre>
```

Or, even better, use an external CSS stylesheet to avoid mixing CSS and HTML.